# preg match all for repeating pattern

Tags: preg-match-all

Trying to match all occurences of pattern:

[xx]Any characters

example string: [en]Any characters[fr]Any characters 2

[xx] = always equals two lowercase letters

Looking for an array similar to this

```
0
 0 - [en]
 1 - Any characters
1
 0 - [fr]
 1 - Any characters 2
```

Or even better, like this

```
0
 0 - [en]
 1 - [fr]
1
 0 - Any characters
 1 - Any characters 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
@\[([a-z]{2})\]([^\[]*)@
```

second () will match anything but [